# Скрыть child view в CoordinatorLayout с BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-support-library

В **support library 23.2.0** появился **BottomSheetBehavior**.

Как скрыть элемент в `CoordinatorLayout` c установленным `BottomSheetBehavior`, чтобы `CoordinatorLayout` корректно изменил размер?

мета-layout

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <CoordinatorLayout
   app:behavior="BottomSheetBehavior">
     <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
       <View1/>
       <View2/>
       <View3/>
     </LinearLayout>
  </CoordinatorLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

В коде:

```
View2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

[Схожая проблема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897708/android-problemn-when-setting-visibility-in-coordinatorlayout)

[Вопрос один в один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685681/dynamically-change-height-of-bottomsheetbehavior)

[image: layout]

Comment: Разметку приведите. У вас два вложенных координатора... И при чем тут BottomSheetBehavior тоже непонятно.

Comment: @YuraIvanov
http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html
 "By attaching a BottomSheetBehavior to a child View of a CoordinatorLayout (i.e., adding app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"), you’ll automatically get the appropriate touch detection ..."

Comment: Эта цитата никаким образом не корректирует с вашим вопросом. Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример того, что у вас не получается добиться. Пока есть лишь подозрение что вы не понимаете принципа работы coordinatorLayout'а и behaviors.